# WPF: How can I set image source from DLL resource file?

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I set image source from DLL resource file?

```
<Image Source="res/png_32.png" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
```

It works fine, but my image are located as resource in the DLL file. How can I get it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would handle this via a [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx):

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/TheDLLName;component/res/png_32.png" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
```

Comment: Thank you. Look the screen please: http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20130814/DH22HzJ0.png

I tried some variants, but all ain't working for me:

pack://application:,,,/456.dll;component/Resource.rc/Bitmap/bmp_32.bmp

pack://application:,,,/456.dll;component/Bitmap/bmp_32.bmp

pack://application:,,,/456.dll;component/res/bmp_32.bmp

:(

Comment: @Bush Leave off the ".dll"

Comment: Ain't helps too. :( Which paths is not rights (according my screen)?

Comment: @Bush Oh - I just realized, you're trying to load an unmanaged (native) resource - this isn't directly supported.  I'd recommend putting the resource in a C# project, but if that's not an option, you can use P/Invoke to load it.  See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/82a53f08-5d04-4902-9a67-2f77bf951ba4/extract-unmanaged-native-resources-using-c